# Is it possible to have a mapping to a tuple?

Tags: solidity, mapping

Is it possible to have a mapping where the values are a tuple?

```
mapping (address => (bool, uint)) participants;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use a struct, eg

```
struct Participant {
    bool value1;
    uint value2;
}

mapping (address => Participant) participants;
```

I don't think there's any way of using an actual Tuple eg `var (a, b)` in a mapping since the types of `a` and `b` cannot be declared with the syntax available. With a struct the types can be declared, which is necessary to declare the mapping type.